# Is there a way in QGIS 3 to get a selected feature WKT?

Tags: qgis-plugins, well-known-text, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.x, I used the **getWkt** [image: getWkt] plugin: https://github.com/hugoledoux/QGIS-getWKT to get a WKT of a selected feature.

But that plugin isn't present in QGIS 3.x.  Was that capability built into core QGIS 3?  Or is this a case where we are waiting for the plugin to catch up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not sure if this was actually part of QGIS 2.x since I always used the getWKT plugin.  But the WKT is accessible from the Identify window context menu:  [image]

Result:

```
wkt_geom    id  OBJECTID    ID_0    ISO NAME_0  ID_1    NAME_1  ID_2    NAME_2  HASC_2  CCN_2   CCA_2   TYPE_2  ENGTYPE_2   NL_NAME_2   VARNAME_2   Shape_Length    Shape_Area
MultiPolygon (((-86.1056060791015625 34.20109939575195313, -86.10605621337890625 34.22154998779296875, -86.10604095458984375 34.22610092163091622, -86.10703277587890625 34.25019073486328125, -86.10832214355457381 34.32471084594732247, -86.10830688476556816 34.32788848876958809, -86.1097869873046875 34.36470031738286934, -86.10974121093744316 34.37469863891607247, -86.11003112792963066 34.42784881591802559, -86.05683135986328125 34.47628021240240059, -86.04846954345703125 34.47669982910167619, -86.03733062744134941 34.47574996948242188, -86.03174591064453125 34.47526931762706681, -86.02672576904296875 34.47661209106456681, -86.02169036865228691 34.48067855834960938, -86.0177764892578125 34.48247909545904122, -86.01275634765619316 34.48200988769536934, -86.00663757324213066 34.48107147216808244, -86.00216674804681816 34.48196029663097306, -85.99098205566400566 34.48736953735351563, -85.98596954345703125 34.48688888549816056, -85.9837188720703125 34.490509033203125, -85.97757720947265625 34.49139022827148438, -85.96972656249994316 34.4968109130859375, -85.96190643310541191 34.49950027465831681, -85.95966339111328125 34.50222015380865059, -85.9568328857421875 34.507659912109375, -85.9383087158203125 34.52527999877924003, -85.9231719970703125 34.53520965576177559, -85.91980743408203125 34.53701019287103691, -85.91082763671875 34.54423141479492188, -85.881683349609375 34.5622406005859375, -85.86540985107416191 34.57260894775396309, -85.839019775390625 34.5897216796875, -85.8244171142578125 34.59962844848644181, -85.81993103027332381 34.60187911987310372, -85.81488037109375 34.60548019409185372, -85.81262969970703125 34.60683059692388497, -85.78566741943353691 34.62438201904296875, -85.76193237304681816 34.65375900268560372, -85.73532867431634941 34.68856048583990059, -85.733062744140625 34.69173049926763497, -85.72173309326171875 34.70664978027349434, -85.71833801269525566 34.7102508544921875, -85.69338226318359375 34.74415206909185372, -85.67267608642572441 34.74536895751958809, -85.65912628173822441 34.75661849975597306, -85.64827728271484375 34.77561950683588066, -85.63632965087884941 34.79415130615234375, -85.63404083251947441 34.79867935180669747, -85.634002685546875 34.80186080932617188, -85.63387298583984375 34.81412124633789063, -85.62696075439453125 34.83042144775390625, -85.60381317138666191 34.84749984741210938, -85.603759765625 34.85113143920904122, -85.60205078125 34.85338973999023438, -85.5970001220703125 34.85425949096691056, -85.58358764648431816 34.86230087280284806, -85.57299804687494316 34.80289077758794747, -85.53456878662103691 34.62474060058605119, -85.5322265625 34.61392974853515625, -85.52683258056634941 34.58852005004888497, -85.51317596435546875 34.52474975585948869, -85.52217102050775566 34.52661895751958809, -85.52498626708984375 34.52347183227544747, -85.52558898925775566 34.52074050903320313, -85.52284240722650566 34.51708984375005684, -85.52731323242181816 34.51713180541992188, -85.53235626220703125 34.51490020751953125, -85.53459930419921875 34.51354980468744316, -85.535186767578125 34.51082992553710938, -85.5408172607421875 34.50632858276372872, -85.54480743408203125 34.50001144409185372, -85.5475921630859375 34.500030517578125, -85.5509033203125 34.50323867797857247, -85.55480194091791191 34.50371932983409806, -85.55871582031238631 34.50239181518549003, -85.55771636962890625 34.49238967895513497, -85.559417724609375 34.49058914184570313, -85.56835174560535506 34.48974990844737931, -85.57063293457025566 34.4861297607421875, -85.5767822265625 34.48390960693365059, -85.57459259033203125 34.48070907592773438, -85.57350158691394881 34.47888946533203125, -85.57071685791009941 34.47795867919927559, -85.5702972412109375 34.46704864501953125, -85.57639312744140625 34.47072982788080253, -85.5808563232421875 34.46986007690435372, -85.577606201171875 34.46165847778325997, -85.57930755615228691 34.45940017700200997, -85.58377075195306816 34.45851898193365059, -85.57946014404296875 34.44622039794916191, -85.57897186279296875 34.44031143188482247, -85.5818023681640625 34.43669891357421875, -85.58351898193359375 34.43307876586919747, -85.59079742431640625 34.42950057983409806, -85.58863067626947441 34.42494201660161934, -85.600921630859375 34.42140197753917619, -85.59931945800775566 34.41548156738292619, -85.60381317138666191 34.41324996948247872, -85.60716247558582381 34.4119110107421875, -85.60830688476551131 34.4082794189453125, -85.61112213134765625 34.40649032592773438, -85.61458587646478691 34.39514923095703125, -85.6173858642578125 34.39381027221691056, -85.62680816650379256 34.39797210693353691, -85.62740325927734375 34.39480209350597306, -85.62464141845703125 34.39295959472667619, -85.61968994140625 34.38747024536138497, -85.624755859375 34.38251113891607247, -85.62754058837884941 34.38253021240234375, -85.63034820556640625 34.380279541015625, -85.62818145751953125 34.37525939941417619, -85.62819671630859375 34.3730010986328125, -85.632110595703125 34.37211990356439628, -85.635498046875 34.36804962158203125, -85.63662719726556816 34.36669921875, -85.64108276367181816 34.366729736328125, -85.64272308349603691 34.36946868896490059, -85.6449432373046875 34.36994171142578125, -85.64778900146473006 34.36405181884765625, -85.66282653808588066 34.36280059814458809, -85.6684417724609375 34.35874938964849434, -85.66848754882801131 34.35466003417980119, -85.67241668701171875 34.35150909423833809, -85.676361083984375 34.34698867797851563, -85.67472076416015625 34.34379959106450997, -85.67865753173822441 34.34019088745122872, -85.77178192138671875 34.26084136962890625, -85.7779083251953125 34.25905990600585938, -85.80847930908197441 34.25923919677740059, -85.80921173095697441 34.23971176147472306, -85.81086730957019881 34.23971939086925431, -85.81755828857421875 34.23884963989257813, -85.8253173828125 34.24071884155273438, -85.83030700683588066 34.24164962768566056, -85.8436279296875 34.24444961547857247, -85.84343719482421875 34.19992065429693184, -86.01341247558588066 34.19984054565441056, -86.02507781982421875 34.19989013671880684, -86.04508209228509941 34.19997024536138497, -86.06896209716796875 34.20051956176757813, -86.09284210205072441 34.20059967041015625, -86.10173034667963066 34.20109176635742188, -86.1056060791015625 34.20109939575195313)))  25  25  244 USA United States   1   Alabama 25  De Kalb US.AL.DA    0       County  County          2.16771912642183    0.197712887515082
```

**Update:**
The behavior of the copy feature can be modified in the `Options | Data Sources | Feature attributes and table | Copy features as`:
[image]

So if this is set to GeoJson or no geometry, you need to use a secondary option to get the WKT (see other answers to this question).

Comment: You could also do this in QGIS 2.x, or atleast in 2.18 :)

Comment: thanks! that doesn't surprise me--there's probably numerous cases of plugins obscuring core functionality.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this fills your needs but you can (and always could) get the WKT from the field calculator by adding a virtual layer with:

```
geomToWKT( $geometry )
```

[image]

Comment: To have it in any CRS you want (e.g. EPSG:4326 here) it would be: `geom_to_wkt(transform($geometry, @layer_crs, 'EPSG:4326'))`

Answer (score 8):

You could also use the following in the **Python Console** (although your method would be quicker):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
    print(feat.geometry().asWkt())
```

Answer (score 4):

Having some features selected you can simply copy the features using the copy button or Ctrl+c.

Then you can paste in on a spreadsheet sheet or notepad. The geometry column will be represented in WKT.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get WKT, like creating a field (virtual or not) with the expression mentioned earlier.

But for your original question about QuickWKT, this plugin has been ported to QGIS 3. Check your plugin manager.

Answer (score 0):

getWKT plugin has been ported to QGIS 3.0

[image]